Use pruning with snapshot
I want to use polkadot chain snapshot from https://snapshots.polkadot.io/ to restore my mainnet node, but my requirement is to keep state data for 100800 blocks, while in snapshot it is showing only for -state-pruning to 256 or 1000 blocks, how can I achieve this configuration?

Currently, it's not supported to increase that number for a synced pruned DB.
You have to sync from the start yourself. However, you might want to try warp-sync; I believe it's better than using a snapshot.
Since that feature has been stabilized, I no longer use snapshots.

Thanks for the inputs, so warp-sync will sync from the latest? What about historical data, as I want to keep state data for 100800 blocks, will --pruning 100800 suffice with warp sync

It will synchronize all data and create a block based on the most recent information simultaneously. Once the synchronization is complete, you may include that pruning flag.
